# Pandas create column of dictionaries based on condition from another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

Let's say if I have a Pandas df called `df_1` like this:

| id | date_created | rank_1 | rank_2 | rank_3 | rank_dict |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2223 | 3/3/21 3:26 | www.google.com | [www.yahoo.com](http://www.yahoo.com) | [www.ford.com](http://www.ford.com) | {www.google.com:3, [www.yahoo.com:2](http://www.yahoo.com:2), [www.ford.com:1}](http://www.ford.com:1%7D) |
| 1112 | 2/25/21 1:35 | www.autoblog.com | www.motor1.com | www.webull.com | {www.autoblog.com:3, [www.motor1.com:2](http://www.motor1.com:2), [www.webull.com:1}](http://www.webull.com:1%7D) |

and another df called `df_2` that looks like this:

| id | date_created | rank_1 | rank_2 | rank_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2223 | 4/9/21 5:15 | [www.yahoo.com](http://www.yahoo.com) | [www.whatever.com](http://www.whatever.com) | www.google.com |
| 1112 | 8/20/21 2:30 | [www.gm.com](http://www.gm.com) | [www.motor1.com](http://www.motor1.com) | www.webull.com |

I want to create a new column called `new_rank_dict` in `df_2` using URLs in rank_1, rank_2, rank_3 in `df_2` as Keys, and Values created using the following criteria:

- Look up the row in `df_1` that has matching `id`, if the rank_1 URL exists in the Keys of `rank_dict` from `df_1` for that row, assign the same Value as it was seen from that dictionary. If the `rank_1` URL doesn't exist in that dictionary, assign a Value of 0 to it.
- Do the same for `rank_2` and `rank_3`, and finally will end up with a dictionary for each row in `df_2`.

For example, since row 1 in `df_1` and `df_2` share the same `id` (2223), and `rank_1` ([www.yahoo.com](http://www.yahoo.com)) in `df_2` is a Key in `rank_dict` in `df_1`, and that Key has value of 2, then assign Value of 2 to the [www.yahoo.com](http://www.yahoo.com) Key. `rank_2` ([www.whatever.com](http://www.whatever.com)) doesn't exist in `rank_dict` in `df_1`, so it gets a Value of 0. `rank_3` ([www.google.com](http://www.google.com)) does exist in `rank_dict` in `df_1` and its Value is 3, so assign the Value 3 to that Key for the new dictionary. At the end, row 1 in `df_2` will have the `new_rank_dict`: `{www.yahoo.com:2, www.whatever.com:0, www.google.com:3}`

So the ideal result `df_2` should look like this:

| id | date_created | rank_1 | rank_2 | rank_3 | rank_dict |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2223 | 4/9/21 5:15 | www.yahoo.com | [www.whatever.com](http://www.whatever.com) | [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) | {www.yahoo.com:2, [www.whatever.com:0](http://www.whatever.com:0), [www.google.com:3}](http://www.google.com:3%7D) |
| 1112 | 8/20/21 2:30 | www.gm.com | www.motor1.com | www.webull.com | {www.gm.com:0, [www.motor1.com:2](http://www.motor1.com:2), [www.webull.com:1}](http://www.webull.com:1%7D) |

I have been struggling to find a Pythonic way to achieve this goal efficiently - have searched on the web and most tutorials point to create a single dictionary from Pandas column, rather than a column of dictionary which is what I need here.

Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Code

```
dcts = df2['id'].map(df1.set_index('id')['rank_dict'])
cols = df2.filter(like='rank')

df2['rank_dict'] = [{u: dct.get(u, 0) for u in urls}
                    for urls, dct in zip(cols.values, dcts)]
```

#### Explanations

`map` the column `rank_dict` from `df1` to `df2` based on the common `id`

```
>>> dcts

0         {'www.google.com': 3, 'www.yahoo.com': 2, 'www.ford.com': 1}
1    {'www.autoblog.com': 3, 'www.motor1.com': 2, 'www.webull.com': 1}
Name: id, dtype: object
```

Now filter the `rank` like columns from `df2`:

```
>>> cols
          rank_1            rank_2          rank_3
0  www.yahoo.com  www.whatever.com  www.google.com
1     www.gm.com    www.motor1.com  www.webull.com
```

`zip` the `cols` and `dcts`, then iterate over this zip iterator inside a list comprehension to create a required dictionary that satisfies the given criteria.

```
>>> df2

     id  date_created         rank_1            rank_2          rank_3                                                         rank_dict
0  2223   4/9/21 5:15  www.yahoo.com  www.whatever.com  www.google.com  {'www.yahoo.com': 2, 'www.whatever.com': 0, 'www.google.com': 3}
1  1112  8/20/21 2:30     www.gm.com    www.motor1.com  www.webull.com       {'www.gm.com': 0, 'www.motor1.com': 2, 'www.webull.com': 1}
```

Comment: Thank you @Shubham Sharma! It works perfectly. I never thought to use `{u: dct.get(u, 0) for u in urls}` method to assign the value to matching keys. It's very clever method.

Comment: Glad I could help!